# PDO BindParam short cut?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm new to using PDO but I'm kinda confused using the bindParam function. Is it possible to avoid using the bindParam? If not - why?

I'm using a stored procedure like so

```
$e = 'example@g.com';
$p = 'pass123';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL GetUserByEmail($e, $p) );
$stmt->execute();
```

I then want to check the result table for how many results there are.. why I'm also not sure how to do - I'm used to using the mysqli_ functions. Thanks!

Comment: in `$stmt->execute();` you can pass an array of the items in the order that they appear in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have your prepared statement, call the `execute` function on it, with an array of parameters as the only argument.

There is a difference between named parameters and 'ordered' parameters: the first have a name (associative array), the latter have only a position (normal array).

Example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL GetUserByEmail(?, ?)");
$stmt -> execute(array($e, $p));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL GetUserByEmail(:emails, :passwords)");
$stmt -> execute(array(':emails' => $e, ':passwords' => $p));
```

Also see the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php.

---

To get the amount of rows, call the `rowCount` function on the result:

```
$stmt -> rowCount(); // Amount of rows selected
```

Comment: And the $stmt->rowCount() would be called after execute right?

Comment: it takes `:` in front of the `:names` and `:password` in the array you pass to execute. see you own documentation link, exemple 2

Comment: and it would be better if `:emails` matched `:names` :p